# Is there an easy way to create a new Wildfly server instance

Tags: jboss5.x, wildfly

Is there an easy way to create a new Wildfly server instance.

In JBoss AS5 all you had to do is create a copy of default or all and start jboss with:

```
run.sh -c [New instance name]
```

There is no such option available in `standalone.sh`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The change which started with the JBoss AS7 and continues in WildFly is, the whole server configuration is hold in a single file. There are prepared some 4 default configurations (or profiles):

- default (`standalone.xml` - used by default - without clustering and messaging)
- HA (`standalone-ha.xml` - supports clustering)
- Full (`standalone-full.xml` - supports messaging)
- Full HA (`standalone-full-ha.xml` - supports both messaging and clustering)

To use the custom profile start the server with using `-c` switch

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml
```

If you only need to change the server configuration, you can edit the profile XML files directly, use CLI tool (`jboss-cli.sh/bat`) or management console.

If you want to do bigger changes (e.g. different applications in `standalone/deployments` directory), you can copy the whole `standalone` directory and edit each copy as necessary. I use following way for starting two clustered server:

```sh
cd $JBOSS_HOME
cp -r standalone standalone1; cp -r standalone standalone2
# edit the configs here if necessary ...
bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml \
    -Djboss.server.base.dir=`pwd`/standalone1 \
    -Djboss.node.name=host1 &
bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml \
    -Djboss.server.base.dir=`pwd`/standalone2 \
    -Djboss.node.name=host2 \
    -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=200 &
```

This example creates 2 copies from a clean `standalone` configuration and starts a server for each copy. The second server have port offset 200 (e.g. web running on port 8280).

Comment: I used the command "./standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml -b 10.10.10.10 -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.server.base.dir=../standalone-node1 -Djboss.node.name=node1 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100"  and kept on getting ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.network.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public  Error

Answer (score 0):

For standalone instances you can use the `--server-config` or `-c` option to specify a different configuration. 
For example, to put JBoss in *"clustered"* mode

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-ha.xml
```

Other alternative is used a domain mode configuration, in this mode you can define different profiles, for an different servers instances.

[WildFly - Operating modes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Operating+modes)
[WildFly - Domain Setup](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Domain+Setup)