# How to know if WildFly is running with Web Profile or Full Profile?

Tags: wildfly, application-server, jakarta-ee

I am exploring WildFly first time. I have installed WildFly 8.2.1.Final. As I can see in the Standalone mode it can be run with 2 profiles: Web Profile and Full Profile.

How to know for a currently running WildFly that if it is running with Web Profile or Full Profile?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400059/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-a-new-wildfly-server-instance

Comment: @happy Thanks for the link but this is not what I am looking for. Suppose there is a WildFly running on a server and I don't know if it was started with `standalone.xml` or `standalone-full.xml`. Is there any way (through its console) to figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short answer: no.

longer answer:
Wildfly doesn't really have any internal distinction between web-profile and full-profile. The configuration is all there is. The default standalone.xml configuration is a certified web-distribution but Wildfly doesn't know that.

As you add or remove extensions in the configuration you are making it non-standard in terms of configuration. For example, if you add the JMS extension to web-profile you will be running something that isn't web or full profile.

Wildfly 10 is shipping with a 'servlet' profile that is even more stripped down than web profile because people tend to want to customize a lot.

As to knowing what you are running, the best way to tell this at runtime is to:

```
- connect with jboss-cli.sh
- run the command: ls extension
```

this will give you a list of running extensions and you can check for the presence of the ones you care about.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me Windows equivalent of what you suggested the best way to tell at runtime? We are running all Windows here.

Comment: I don't know windows. But there should be a .bat equivalent in the bin directory.